# If value exist (not primary key) in table, return table id (primary key)?

Tags: php, mysql

Element by there id (primary key) or any other alternative for doing that, I used `MySQL_num_rows()` for checking existence of value it works fine how to change the specified row values of columns without id(primary key) of row. Please provide some code if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns array of results including all the columns that you got through the query. What you need to do is,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo $row["primary_key"];
echo $row["other_value"];

if($row["other_value"]==something)
{
    //Update the table with $row["primary_key"]
}

}
```